# plantuml requires a header argument (Emacs 24 on Windows' Ubuntu Subsystem)

Tags: org-mode, microsoft-windows, ubuntu

I'm trying to output images using `plantuml-mode`.  It seems I have `plantuml-mode` installed successfully, as I can activate the major mode, but I am unable to evaluate using `C-c C-c`:

PlantUML requires a ":file" header argument

Here is the code I am trying to evaluate:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml
@startuml
(*) --> "First Activity"
-->[You can put also labels] "Second Activity"
--> (*)
@enduml
#+END_SRC
```

And here is what I have in my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'plantuml-mode)
(require 'ob-plantuml)
(add-to-list
   'org-src-lang-modes '("plantuml" . plantuml))
```

I have tried using `plantuml-mode` on a mac before and I never had to manually set a header argument.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file my_file.jpg
```

gives you a `jpg` file

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file my_file.png
```

gives you a `png` file

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file my_file.txt
```

gives you a `txt` file

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file my_file.svg
```

gives you a `svg` file

The images are produced by  `imagemagick`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After looking at the source code I figured out it is expecting a file name as a parameter. This code should work:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC plantuml :file plantuml.svg
@startuml
(*) --> "First Activity"
-->[You can put also labels] "Second Activity"
--> (*)
@enduml
#+END_SRC
```